# Assembly references missing errors while building solution on TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild

i have a solution which contains 3 projects (DAL,BLL and Utility) and one website.

I tried to build solution locally but it was giving some missing references errors. i added missing dll's and build was success locally.

i checked in whole solution to TFS 2013 server. and tried to build solution on tfs through build definition. Butbuild fails with many errors (missing assembly reference).

in source control i cant see any bin file so that i can add dlls.

What am i missing? how can i add referenced to a project on TFS?

Answer (score 0):

You should not check binaries into any source control system.

If your referenced assemblies are available on Nuget then use nuget to reference them correctly.

If your referenced assemblies are not on Nuget them you should package them as a Nuget package, stick it on a fileshare (or better yet MyGet), and take a reference on that Nuget package.

The question is irrelevant, the answer is nuget